# Jenkins view regular expression

Tags: regex, view, jenkins

I have jobs in Jenkins that are named in this manner:

```
Dev.paas.****.****
Qa.paas.****.****
Stg.paas.****.****
Dev.pui.****.****
.
.
.
etc.
```

I'm trying to create a view that only shows `paas`, I enabled regex and I put the following:

`*.paas.*`

But Jenkins didn't like that and gave me an error.

[image]

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The asterisk `*` carries special semantics in regular expressions ( namely 'any number of repetitions, including no occurrence at all' ).

Basic regular expressions match at any position in the test string. Therefore you do not need to describe the complete target string(s) in the regular expression., though it is good practice to do so in order to avoid false positives and to potentially speed up execution.

In short:

- Just drop the leading `*`, or
- precede the leading `*` with a `.` (matches any character except newline/line feed), or
- (recommended) make sure that `paas` is only matched between two full stop characters: `\.paas\.` ( since `.` has a special meaning in regular expressions, , you have to escape it ).

Comment: Thanks, this `.*.paas.*` ended up working just fine for me! :)

Comment: Thanks @collapsar not sure why the jenkins plugin's own help are not that great. I always tend to find more info on StackOverflow. Even after 4 years your answer is helping other people. :)

Answer (score 1):

Also I think this seems to be case-sensitive. So if the folder name is Paas or PAAS, then it may not come in the filtered list of .*paas.*