# Jenkins view regular expression include text

Tags: regex, jenkins

Okay so I have a fair few pipelines/jobs and I would like to filter them using the view "tab" from Jenkins.

They offer a regex filter option but whatever I input there does not seem to filter in any way. Wether it's erroneous regex, correct regex or just nothing or even a single star, zero jobs are included.

Is there something specific to do there?

Specifically, I'm would like to filter only jobs containing the "=" character, or the word "Ref" (case sensitive) if it's any simpler to write.

I have tried using

```
/Ref/
/*Ref*/
Ref
/Ref
/*Ref*
And all the same with =, as well as other "text" regexes and none match
```

Note that there are always characters before and after the equal sign or the Ref word, the job name is a string never including spaces.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922500/jenkins-view-regular-expression you can check this and use ".*.Ref.*" for same

Answer (score 4):

In regex, * just matches zero or more of the previous character.
So you can use the dot character [.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) to match (almost any character), followed by * to match zero or more of them.

So the full regex could be:

```
.*Ref.*|.*=.*
```

This to match either **Ref** OR (denoted by **|**) **=** within a job name.

**Ref** or **=** could be embedded in the job name (or at beginning or end) hence surrounding both with **.***

If you want 2 separate views, you'd need 2 regexes. For jobs containing **Ref**:

```
.*Ref.*
```

For jobs containing **=**

```
.*=.*
```

I've tested this locally on my jenkins and it seems to work.
[image]